# JQuery check all checkboxes in column

Tags: jquery

I had this table:
[image: my table]

When i click 'Check all' in one column, its supposed that all check boxes in that column with be checked and otherwise. 
Here is my JQuqey:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^="check_"]').on('click', function(){
        perm_type=$(this).attr('id');
        type=perm_type.substring(6);

        if(!($('#check_'+type).attr('checked'))) {
            $("[id^=client_type_"+type+"]").attr('checked', true);
            $('#check_'+type).attr('checked', true);
            }
        else  {
            $("[id^=client_type_"+type+"]").attr('checked',false);
            $('#check_'+type).attr('checked',false);
            }

    });
});
```

There is my html:

```
echo '<tr bgcolor="'.($bgcol[$inx % 2]).'"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';  
            echo '<tr bgcolor="'.($bgcol[$inx % 2]).'">';           
            echo '<td valign="top" align="center"><b>';
            echo $row['title'];
            echo '</b></td>';
            echo '<td valign="top" align="center">';
            echo '<b>Clients Types</b>';
            echo '</td>';       
            echo '<td valign="top" align="center">';
            echo "<input type='checkbox' id='check_select'>  Check all";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td valign="top" align="center">';
            echo "<input type='checkbox' id='check_insert'> Check all";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td valign="top" align="center">';
            echo "<input type='checkbox' id='check_update'> Check all";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td valign="top" align="center">';
            echo "<input type='checkbox' id='check_delete'> Check all";
            echo '</td>';                   
            echo "</tr>";

            $nr=0;
            $cli = //my query  here;
              $result=$db->sql_query($cli);
              while($r=$db->sql_fetchrow($result)){  
            $s =$db->sql_fetchrow($db->sql_query(//my query here"));

            echo '<tr bgcolor="'.($bgcol[$inx % 2]).'">';           
            echo '<td></td><td valign="top" align="center">';
            echo $r['type'];
            echo "<input type='hidden' id='cli_type_id".$nr."' value='".$r['type_id']."'>";
            echo '</td>';   
            echo '<td valign="top" align="center">';
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='rights[".$r['type_id']."][select]' id='client_type_select".$nr."'  value='true' "; echo $s['sel']?"checked":""; echo ">";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td valign="top" align="center">';
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='rights[".$r['type_id']."][insert]' id='client_type_insert".$nr."' value='true' "; echo $s['ins']?"checked":""; echo ">";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td valign="top" align="center">';
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='rights[".$r['type_id']."][update]' id='client_type_update".$nr."' value='true' "; echo $s['upd']?"checked":""; echo ">";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td valign="top" align="center">';
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='rights[".$r['type_id']."][delete]' id='client_type_delete".$nr."' value='true' "; echo $s['del']?"checked":""; echo ">";
            echo '</td>';                   
            echo "</tr>";
              $nr++;  
             }
```

The current result is: When 1 check/uncheck for the first time 'check all', it does function, but if i check again 'check all', is doesn't nothing.
Please anybody help me!

Comment: Having the HTML instead of the PHP would be more convenient.

Comment: Show the actual HTML markup.  The server-side PHP code is useless, since the client-side JavaScript code doesn't interact with that.  Also, when you debug the JavaScript, on what line do you get unexpected behavior?  Are you parsing out the values you expect?  Do your jQuery selectors find the elements you expect?

Comment: Why do you intercept the click event instead of change ? This makes you change the checkbox yourself.

Comment: here is good example for you [Link][1]


  [1]: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/422713/Check-all-checkboxes-in-GridView-using-jQuery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll guess :

```
$(function() {
    $('[id^="check_"]').on('change', function(){
        var type = this.id.split('_')[1];

        $('[id^="client_type_'+type+'"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: +1 for using the actual checkbox element, rather than unnecessarily wrapping it in a `$` object.

Comment: However I wrapped it to get at the prop and I posted first too :)

Comment: @mplungjan - took me like ten minutes to figure out all the elements, attributes and styles in that horrible PHP code, but you where faster indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Based and inspired by http://beckelman.net/2008/11/18/select-all-checkboxes-in-a-table-column-with-and-without-jquery-plugin-demo/ but for all columns in the table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tableOne thead tr th input:checkbox").click(function() {
            var checkedStatus = this.checked;
            var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
            $("#tableOne tbody tr td:nth-child("+index+") input:checkbox").each(function() {
                this.checked = checkedStatus;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

+1 to the other answers but for a more generic solution:

```
$('[id^="check_"]').on('change', function(){
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    var index = $(this).parent().index();

    $('tr').each(function(i, val){
        $(val).children().eq(index).children('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', checked);
    });
});
```

Might be useful if anyone ends up on this question with the same problem, but doesn't have the types coded into the checkbox names. This works by looking at the column instead.

Answer (score 2):

Without testing the code since it is PHP I would suggest something like this. I keep the click event since I distrust the change event that (used to) only trigger when fields are blurred
I also user $(this).prop instead of this.checked to be sure.

```
$('[id^="check_"]').on('click', function(){
  var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
  var type=this.id.split("_")[1];
  $("[id^=client_type_"+type+"]").prop("checked",checked);
});
```