# Select all checkbox in the same column

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, checkbox

I am trying to implement something similar to [Checking checkbox in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149434/jquery-check-all-checkboxes-in-column)

I have two select all checkboxes in a table and selecting one would select all the checkboxes of the same column.

It an ASP.NET GridView. [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TDjQmyjAUVVJZbTxFByf?p=preview)

```
function CheckHeaderCheckboxAll(obj, gridname) {    
    var objId = obj.id;
    var table= $(obj).closest('table');
    $('td input:checkbox',table).prop('checked',this.checked);
}
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Is `obj` the checkbox that is checked?

Comment: `this` refer to nothing here

Comment: Yes @epascarello. The obj is the checkbox thats checked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic idea is to select the cell, get the index, and than select the other table cells of the table with that index.

```js
$("th input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
   var cb = $(this),          //checkbox that was changed
       th = cb.parent(),      //get parent th
       col = th.index() + 1;  //get column index. note nth-child starts at 1, not zero
   $("tbody td:nth-child(" + col + ") input").prop("checked", this.checked);  //select the inputs and [un]check it
});
```

```css
th { background-color: #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want to do it with inline event handler like you have it, your code would look like

```
function CheckHeaderCheckboxAll(obj) {
   var cb = $(obj),           //checkbox that was changed
       th = cb.parent(),      //get parent th
       col = th.index() + 1;  //get column index. note nth-child starts at 1, not zero
   $("tbody td:nth-child(" + col + ") input").prop("checked", obj.checked);  //select the inputs and [un]check it
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to write `$("tbody td:nth-child(" + col + ") input").prop("checked", obj.checked);` from this answer [how-to-check-and-uncheck-all-checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17814273/769678)but was getting syntax error. I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the on click event. rather bind it with class.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" class="checkAll" data-class="class1" name="checkAll" id="ctl00_UserMasterContentPlaceHolder_grdUserDetails_ctl01_chkHeaderCheckbox"/>
```

Give the class name which you want to check

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" class="class1" />
```

Try this jquery:

```
$(".checkAll").click(function () {
     var datacls = $(this).attr('data-class');
     $('input:checkbox.'+datacls).not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well what `@epascarello` said is probably better.

I just have a minor suggestion and that would be *finding the checkboxes from the same table itself* otherwise it would end up selecting checkboxes present in all the tables of the page:

```js
function SelectAll(obj) {

  // find the index of column
  var table = $(obj).closest('table'); // find the current table
  var th_s = table.find('th'); // find/get all the <th> of current table
  var current_th = $(obj).closest('th'); // get current <th>

  // the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1
  var columnIndex = th_s.index(current_th) + 1; // find index of current <th> within list of <th>'s

  console.log('The Column is = ' + columnIndex); // print the index for testing

  // select all checkboxes from the same column index of the same table
  table.find('td:nth-child(' + (columnIndex) + ') input').prop("checked", obj.checked);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="SelectAll(this)" />
    </th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="SelectAll(this)" />Is Active</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="isActive" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Tim</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="isActive" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<h2>
Another Table<hr/>
</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="SelectAll(this)" />
    </th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="SelectAll(this)" />Is Active</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="isActive" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Tim</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="isActive" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For Reference :

> [nth-child](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/z1yjgo3k/)